# Run animation after animation with no transition in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a frame by frame animation and i want to start another animation on button click with smooth transition (style "tom the cat").

here is the code of the first animation:

```
AnimationDrawable animation;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   animation = new AnimationDrawable();
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m1), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m2), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m3), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m4), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m5), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m6), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m7), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m8), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m9), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m10), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m11), 100);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m12), 100);
   animation.setOneShot(false);

   ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
   imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

   // run the start() method later on the UI thread
   imageAnim.post(new Starter());

}

class Starter implements Runnable {

   public void run() {
       animation.start();        
   }
```

}